# Best Way To Isolate Two Networks On Same Internet Connection?

Tags: networking

I am trying to set up two isolated networks that ultimately go to the same internet connection. These networks, wired or wireless, would be completely isolated from each other so that devices in different networks can not communicate or discover each other. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Oj5.png) is what I have in mind (Device A and Device B cannot communicate).

Is this even possible in an arrangement like this? If not, how could this be achieved?

My apologies for likely a very simple question (I could not find an existing answer). My networking understanding is also still at the basic level.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring VLANs (Virtual LANs) on the switch is the the easiest way to configure logical network isolation.

As long as no routing is enabled between vlans, the device in one vlan will not be able to reach a device in the other vlan.

**More information:**

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/41860-howto-L3-intervlanrouting.html

**Note:**

If there is no switch, or if the switch does not support vlans, then these alternatives can be used:

- Setup a computer or a virtual machine as a gateway for multiple logical networks.
- Setup a router as a gateway for multiple logical networks and configure network access lists to block unwanted cross-network communication.